# Javascript - Optimize algorithm (complex data strcuture)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

### Introduction

I am implementing a method which inserts posts to the respective users posts lists in my map, sorted by date (recent posts first).

This is how I am structuring my data:

```
state = { 
  userId: {
    posts: [
      { // object returned from my feeds algorithm in the server side
        id,
        userData: {
          id,
        },
        date,
      },

      ... more posts ...

    ],
  },

  ... more users ...
}
```

In my algorithm, I just need to insert all the posts that are inside a given list

```
 [
    { id: "post1", { userData: { id: "alex" }, date },
    { id: "post2", { userData: { id: "sara" }, date }
 ]
```

in the posts list of each respective user.

### Problem

I also need to avoid inserting posts that already exists in my state, and I can't find a simple way to do it optimally.

### Current code

This is my current implementation. I feel that this can be done easier and faster. Any help?

```js
/*
  Algorithm
*/

function addContents(state, contents, contentType, cached) {
  const newState = state;

  contents.forEach((content) => {
    const { userData: { id: userId } } = content;

    const prevUserState = state.get(userId);
    const prevContents = prevUserState?.[contentType] ?? [];
    const newContents = prevContents;

    // TODO - Avoid inserting if already exists in prevContents! (check by **id**)

    let inserted = false;

    for (const [index, prevContent] of prevContents.entries()) {
      // Replace
      if (content.id === prevContent.id) {
         newContents[index] = content;
         inserted = true;
         break;
      }

      // Insert in the correct order
      if(content.date >= prevContent.date) {
        newContents.splice(index, 0, content);
        inserted = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!inserted) {
      newContents.push(content);
    }

    newState.set([
      userId,
      {
        ...prevUserState,
        [contentType]: newContents
      }
    ]);
  });

  // if(isEqual(state, newState)) return state; (deep compare to avoid re-renderizations because of state update)

  return new Map([...newState]);
}




/*
  Test
*/


(() => {
  // State
  const state = new Map([]);
  
  // User ALEX
  const userId1 = "alex";
  const userPosts1 = [ // already sorted by date
    {
       id: "78q78w0w0",
       userData: {
        id: userId1,
       },
       date: new Date("10/26/1999 00:00:01")
     },
     {
       id: "92uwdq092",
       userData: {
        id: userId1,
       },
       date: new Date("10/26/1999 00:00:00")
     }
  ];
  state.set(userId1, { posts: userPosts1 });
  
  // User SARA
  const userId2 = "sara";
  const userPosts2 = [ // already sorted by date
    {
       id: "iipzxx115",
       userData: {
        id: userId2,
       },
       date: new Date("12/25/2003 03:30:10")
    },
    {
       id: "Wxrr22232",
       userData: {
        id: userId2,
       },
       date: new Date("01/01/2000 17:44:41")
     }
  ];
  state.set(userId2, { posts: userPosts2 });
  

 
  const newPosts = [
    {
      id: "OLDEST FOR ALEX!",
      userData: {
        id: userId1
      },
      date: new Date("10/25/1999 23:59:59")
    },
    {
      id: "NEWEST FOR SARA!",
      userData: {
        id: userId2
      },
      date: new Date("01/05/2010 22:22:22")
    },
    {
      id: "OLDEST FOR SARA!",
      userData: {
        id: userId2
      },
      date: new Date("10/25/1999 23:59:59")
    }
  ]

  addContents(state, newPosts, "posts");

  console.log(state.get(userId1))
  console.log(state.get(userId2))
})();
```

Note: As this method is implemented in a React's reducer, to manage complex states, I am returning a **new Map**, after deep comparing the previous and the new state, to produce UI re-renderizations.

### UPDATE

I have implemented another version where I do what I need, but maybe, it can be more optimized.

```js
function addContents(state, contents, contentType, cached) {
  const newState = state;

  const exists = {}; // optimization

  for (const content of contents) {
    const {
      userData: { id: userId },
    } = content;

    const prevUserState = state.get(userId);
    const prevContents = prevUserState?.[contentType] ?? [];
    const newContents = prevContents;

    if (cached) {
      if (!exists[userId]) {
        exists[userId] = prevContents.reduce((map, content) => {
          map[content.id] = true;
          return map;
        }, {});
      }

      // Avoid inserting if necessary
      if (exists[userId][content.id]) {
        break;
      }
    }

    // Insert the new content in the user's content list

    console.log(`Inserting ${content.id}`);

    let inserted = false;

    for (const [index, prevContent] of prevContents.entries()) {
      // Replace
      if (content.id === prevContent.id) {
         newContents[index] = content;
         inserted = true;
         break;
      }

      // Insert in the correct order
      if(content.date >= prevContent.date) {
        newContents.splice(index, 0, content);
        inserted = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!inserted) {
      newContents.push(content);
    }

    newState.set([
      userId,
      {
        ...prevUserState,
        [contentType]: newContents
      }
    ]);
  }

  // if (isEqual(state, newState)) return state;

  return new Map([...newState]);
}

/*
  Test
*/


(() => {
  // State
  let state = new Map([]);
  
  // User ALEX
  const userId1 = "alex";
  const userPosts1 = [ // already sorted by date
    {
       id: "78q78w0w0",
       userData: {
        id: userId1,
       },
       date: new Date("10/26/1999 00:00:01")
     },
     {
       id: "92uwdq092",
       userData: {
        id: userId1,
       },
       date: new Date("10/26/1999 00:00:00")
     }
  ];
  state.set(userId1, { posts: userPosts1 });
  
  // User SARA
  const userId2 = "sara";
  const userPosts2 = [ // already sorted by date
    {
       id: "iipzxx115",
       userData: {
        id: userId2,
       },
       date: new Date("12/25/2003 03:30:10")
    },
    {
       id: "Wxrr22232",
       userData: {
        id: userId2,
       },
       date: new Date("01/01/2000 17:44:41")
     }
  ];
  state.set(userId2, { posts: userPosts2 });
  

 
  const newPosts = [
    {
      id: "OLDEST FOR ALEX!",
      userData: {
        id: userId1
      },
      date: new Date("10/25/1999 23:59:59")
    },
    {
      id: "NEWEST FOR SARA!",
      userData: {
        id: userId2
      },
      date: new Date("01/05/2010 22:22:22")
    },
    {
      id: "OLDEST FOR SARA!",
      userData: {
        id: userId2
      },
      date: new Date("10/25/1999 23:59:59")
    }
  ]

  state = addContents(state, newPosts, "posts");

  console.log(state.get(userId1))
  console.log(state.get(userId2))
  
  /*
     Insert again!
  */
  state = addContents(state, newPosts, "posts", true);
})();
```

Comment: How many thousands posts and users are we talking about? Have you benchmarked your solutions? Is this actually a bottleneck?

Comment: @Bergi Normally, from 0 to 100 users, inserting from 0 to 10 posts (not for each user, in total (and might be multiple times)) No, I haven't benchmarked the solution yet, but at a first look, it looks not as optimal as it could be.

Comment: How many posts does each of the 100 users have? But really, this is nothing. [Don't worry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation). Most of the time will actually be spent on copying the `Map`. And unless most of the 10 inserts usually happen on the same user, the `exists` from your update doesn't even help.

Comment: @Bergi, I have two ways to insert posts to my store. I use the method I have described to save the posts that my server returns to the client after executing a "posts feed algorithm". As I am paginating data, from 0 to 10 posts from the same user is inserted in one fetch. Note: the response doesn't return me more than 10 posts (might be owned by different users), it is limited.

Comment: Also, I have another simpler method, where I know who is the user from whom I am downloading posts... So I can do a addUserContents(userId, contents, ...)

Answer (score 1):

use an object instead of an array:
This is the same concept of the `normalizr` library for redux: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

```
state = { 
  [user1Id]: {
    posts: {
      [post1Id]: { 
        id,
        userData: {
          id,
        },
        date,
      },
      [post2Id]: { 
        id,
        userData: {
          id,
        },
        date,
      },

      ... more posts ...

    },
  },

  ... more users ...
}
```

This way you can easily access the object you want by its Id and check whether it exists or not just doing: `if(state[23].posts[12])`
if you need to iterate the users or a user posts use

`object.keys(state).map(userId => ...)`

or

`object.keys(state[23].posts).map(postId => ...)`

INSERT/UPDATE:

`state[23].posts[newId]: { ...newPost}`

Comment: At first I was using the object, but moved to an array so I can update the stateful list of user posts with a sort (by date) on all my routes (something which could happen in parallel).

Comment: BTW, the object reduces complexity... I would need to perform the sorting when I need it, but for updating the state adds the simplicity I need.

Comment: If you need to preserve the order of the original array, use an additional variable, say userOrder which contains the users IDs: `state: { ...., userOrder: [1,25, 10] }` this way you can iterate the state state object mapping the userOrder array.
`const orderedUsers = state.userOrder.map(k => state[k])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to follow what you are doing but I think this is what you are after.
You can do it to a oneline very easy.

```
newdata = [{ id: "post1", { userData: { id: "alex" }, date }]
if(!oldstates.find(d => 
  d.id === newdata.id && 
  d.userData.id === newdata.userData.id && 
  d.date === newdata.date 
)) {
 oldstates.push(newdata)
}
// oneliner
if(!oldstates.find(d => d.id === newdata.id && d.userData.id === newdata.userData.id && d.date === newdata.date )) oldstates.push(newdata)
```

Comment: Applying it inside my loop will cause multiple "searches" around the array.

Comment: Check my update, I think that this way the algorithm will only navigate the prev posts lists one time for each user in order to check existence before the sorted insertion.